# Google drive html website not showing up: error 404

Tags: html, hosting

Google drive hosts html websites for free. I had my html files uploaded in my google drive, and the website was up and running. However, I deleted that folder and tried to repost the website again, but it didn't work. When I re-uploaded the website into my google drive and previewed it, it came up with a 404 error instead of my homepage. Everything is "shared as public on the web." here is my re-uploaded (currently) website folder in my google drive. it only contains an index.html file right now for simplicity.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3UQiV76UmkhYTBhS3B5SnpMSG8&usp=sharing

in summary, my problem is that my google drive website comes up with a 404 error instead of my website. Please help. thanks.

Comment: No CSS,Javascript files are added to that folder...You will have to add those files as well.

Comment: A 404 error means that the requested file is not found. Check tour 'root' again for all existing files!

Comment: I know there are no css or javascript files. I took those out when i posted this question for the sake of simplicity. it doesn't work when they are added either.

Comment: Thanks for your response! what do you mean check the "root?" I have a file named "index.html"... is there something else i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using ***encoded html*** in my website, and that was the thing messing with my google drive hosting. When i removed the encoded html and replaced it with normal html, it all worked perfectly.